# dubbo's annotation @service with spring ioc

Tags: spring

whether dubbo's annotation `@service` will Generating `bean objects` and put it into spring's `ioc` container

so we can only user its `service` `annotation` rather than spring's?

thanks

Comment: Spring also has `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` annotation, not sure if you are referring to something else.

Comment: only use com.alibaba.dubbo.config.annotation.Service  will aslo generate bean and put it into spring's container?

Answer (score 0):

use dubbo annotaion *service*, dubbo will generate bean and put into spring ioc container
if you don't want to use dubbo *service* annotaion, you can use dubbo xml configuration instead.